# Comment puis-je entendre la prononciation phonétique d'un mot ?

Tags: prononciation, phonétique

Bonjour,

j'étais en train de regarder cette définition : https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/poliorc%C3%A9tique#Nom_commun

et je cherche un site (gratuit?) qui permettrait de jouer les sons phonétiques comme celui de ce mot :

> \pɔ.ljɔʁ.se.tik\

Merci.

Comment: [Text-to-speech](http://text-to-speech.imtranslator.net/speech.asp?dir=fr). [poliorcétique](http://tts.imtranslator.net/aQug). Mais il ne prend pas l'API, que des textes en écriture latine ou caractères de langues non latines.

Answer (score 1):

[Text-to-speech](http://text-to-speech.imtranslator.net/speech.asp?dir=fr) permet d'entendre des textes qu'on insère dans le cadre prévu à cet effet. Il faut choisir l'onglet de la langue du texte (10 langues proposées dont le français et l'anglais). On peut mettre des mots qui n'existent pas si on veut, ce n'est pas basé sur une base de données mais sur la reconnaissance du texte écrit.

Il existe un [petit module en ligne](https://speak-ipa.bearbin.net/) qui permet d'entrer des caractères de l'API mais le résultat n'est pas bon du tout. Sinon il y a  [eSpeak text to speech](http://espeak.sourceforge.net/) qui est un logiciel open source qu'on peut télécharger aussi bien pour Linux que pour windows.

--- Edit-----

À peine ma réponse postée que j'ai trouvé une question semblable sur [linguistics.stackexchange](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/9261/637), avec des réponses plus détaillées que la mienne. Je conseille donc de les lire.